# How do I add multiple matrices in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I combine all of these numpy arrays?

```
array([[0.00938241, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.00902791, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.00744846, 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.00607864, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.00508451,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.00731141, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.00747849, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.00603218, 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.00502514, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.00823613,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.00828131, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.00833615, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.0088979 ]])
```

I want to get

```
array([0.00938241, 0.00902791        , 0.00744846        , 0.00607864        , 0.00508451        ,
        0.00731141        ,...])
```

as my ouput i.e. I just want to sum them all up into one array. How do I do this with more than two arrays? I don't see any documentation that addresses this...

Comment: Have you tried `arr.sum(0)`?

Comment: I only see one array. Are you trying to sum along an axis?

Comment: Yes I am. That's right.

Comment: How did you even get this array? It looks like a 2D array with the data you want on the main diagonal. It's very likely that you did something wrong, or at least very suboptimal, while creating this array, and you should probably change the code that created it instead of trying to post-process the output.

Comment: And why am I getting downvoted for this question when, to be honest, Python documentation is so bad that I'm wading through a minefield to answer simple questions like this?

Comment: A good starting point is trying to understand what you have.  As pointed out this is one array (not many).  Print `arr.shape` and `arr.dtype`.  Then the task of adding rows or columns becomes clearer.  Or getting the diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do sum along axis 1

also use `np.array` instead of `pd.Dataarray` which is not defined

```py
arr.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: it is same as the array is diagonal square